# How to download source code of website in java

Tags: java, android

i am new in android development and programming. i was taking some tutorials online for android development and i wanted to download website source code in a string in my app for processing but i was not able to do so. some times the app takes almost 5 to 10 mins to get response but still my app is not able to connect properly below is the code i have used.
Please Help
And please provide me with some troubleshooting methods

Java Code:

```
package com.example.webapp1;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String result = "";
        URL url;
        URLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
                url = new URL(strings[0]);
                urlConnection =url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                 int data = reader.read();

                 while (data != -1)
                 {
                     char current = (char) data;
                     result += current;
                     data = reader.read();
                 }

                 return result;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.getStackTrace();
            return "failed";
        }

    }
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String result =null;
    DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
    try {
        result = task.execute("https://www.imdb.com/list/ls052283250/").get();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i("result content",result);
}
}
```

Android Mainfest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.webapp1">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of errors in your code, and it seems that you are missing the basics of working with Java, files, and Android API.

I would recommend googling for some beginner tutorials, but I don't have a specific one to recommend.

Here are the issues in your code:

1. Your method of accumulating the result by adding `int` variable to `String` is incorrect.
   It will add the numeric value instead of the character that value represents.
   For example, instead of '<' tag, your string will contain "60".
   You should use [`ByteBuffer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/ByteBuffer) or similar.
2. You are not handling the return value correctly:
   You can not get the value of a background (async) task directly back from `execute` method.
   You must [read the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) to learn how to work with AsyncTask class.
   To process the return value of `doInBackground` you must implement `onPostExecute` method!

Android Studio and Android OS provide several tools to troubleshoot code.
The most basic one is logging: [you can use `Log` class](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat) to write information to `logcat` which the studio can display.

Also, [Android Studio comes with a debugger](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug).

Comment: but i am reading Byte inside the loop only `( data = reader.read();)`

Comment: @LakshyaDujari you are right, I missed the read line inside the loop. I edited my answer but please check rest of the issues.

Answer (score 0):

@LevM thanks again i have replaced the existing code with the following but still i am not getting full source code of a website

```
 try
        {
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8"));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
            {
                stringBuilder.append(inputLine);
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Failed";
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return  "Failed";
        }
    }
```

Comment: But what are you getting? Did you implement `onPostExecute`?

Comment: Then you will never get the result of `onDoInBackground`! The result is delivered to `onPostExecute` it is not returned from the `execute` method. The `execute` method returns immediately, but the task continues to run in background. When it is done, `onPostExecute` is called. Read the link I gave in my answer.